# How to import a c++ custom class into c# unity

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, dllimport

I have a DLL file that contains a class that I want to use inside of my c# script in a unity project.

I recently searched about dlls and learned to create dlls and use them inside c#

this is the way i use the dll import attribute to import a method from a dll and use it inside of c#

```
private const string dll= "MyDllFile";

DllImport(Dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern float percent(float percent, float of);
```

The main dll file that i want to work on has a custom class called `Factory` and i want to make an instance of that class which is inside of a dll file in my c# script.

since i don't have the factory class in my c# project, *i can not write something like*

```
DllImport(Dll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern factory(string name);

Factory factory = Factory("myFactory");
```

This won't work because Factory class is a custom class.

the factory() in the dll file, returns an instance of Factory class.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create your  own class with the call to dll inside your class.

Comment: you'll need to wrap your `Factory` class into a set of c functions, SWIG might be helpful

Comment: Or make an in proc com server

Comment: @jdweng can you please give me more detail about it?

Comment: public class MyClass { float p = 12.0; float of = 23.4; float f = percent(percent, of);}

Comment: @jdweng oh, well, that's not my question, i guess you didn't read it completely :D

Comment: I did.  I said you need to put the c++ call into its own instance of a class.

Comment: @jdweng you showed me a good example with a float as the value type for the c++ call.
the function I'm trying to call has an unknown type, i mean, a custom class. what can i put as a type for that? `public class MyClass { float p = 12.0; float of = 23.4; whatTypeInHere f = percent(percent, of);`

Comment: Your dllImport only has two parameters, not three.

Comment: @jdweng well, i said, my dll has a function called Factory() that returns a custom class and i didn't mention how many parameters or fields it has. as i mentioned, percent() is a test function that i created to test some codes. the main dll that im trying to import has a complex function called Factory().

Comment: The dllimport defines the parameters.  Some can be optional.